# Как сортировать по возрастанию архив постов wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wp-query

Имеется код:

```
<div class="b-content" role="main">
    <h1><?php
        if ( is_day() ) :
            printf( __( 'Daily Archives: <span>%s</span>', '' ), get_the_date() );

        elseif ( is_month() ) :
            printf( __( 'Monthly Archives: <span>%s</span>', '' ), get_the_date( _x( 'F Y', 'monthly archives date format', '' ) ) );

        elseif ( is_year() ) :
            printf( __( 'Yearly Archives: <span>%s</span>', '' ), get_the_date( _x( 'Y', 'yearly archives date format', '' ) ) );

        else :
            _e( 'Events Archives', '' );

        endif;
    ?></h1>
    <?php if( ! empty($wp_query->posts) ) : ?>
        <div class="post-list">
            <?php foreach ( $wp_query->posts as $post ) : ?>
                <div class="post-list-item cf">
                    <div class="post-list-date">
                        <span class="post-list-date-day"><?php echo get_the_time( 'j', $post ); ?></span> 
                        <span class="post-list-date-m"><?php echo get_the_time( 'M', $post ); ?></span> 
                        <span class="post-list-date-year"><?php echo get_the_time( 'Y', $post ); ?></span>
                    </div>
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                        <div class="post-list-thumb"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'post-list-thumb' ); ?></a></div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="post-list-descr">
                        <h3 class="post-list-title"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></a></h3>
                        <div class="post-list-excerpt"><?php the_post_excerpt( $post ); ?></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ( function_exists('wp_paginate') ) : wp_paginate(); endif; ?>
</div>
```

не могу разобраться, как использовать

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'orderby'           => 'date',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
)
```

при данном примере

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по коду, это отрывок из файла `archive.php` темы. Здесь работает главный цикл WordPress. Его параметры можно сменить через хук, добавив такой код в functions.php вашей темы

```
/**
 * @param WP_Query $query
 */
function sort_archives( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_archive() ) {
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'sort_archives' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'orderby'           => 'date',
    'order'             => 'ASC'
);
```

DESC - сортировка по убыванию

ASC - сортировка по возрастанию

Comment: это понятно, но куда вставить $args = array